# Finding multiple elements by different tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Before, I had elements like this

```
...
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
```

I used `findElements(By.xpath("td/span"))`

but now they changed one to

```
...
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
<td><a href="myhref">blah blah</a></td>
<td><span>blah blah</span></td>
```

What I am looking for is something (java) like:
`driver.findElements(By.xpath( "td/span" || "td/a" ) )`

Is there a way?

Comment: Please consider adding the extra space, so the code shows up correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove the extra quotes:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath( "td/span | td/a" ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this as well:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/span | //td/a"));
```